# Number of lines on a singular cubic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, singularity-theory

A smooth cubic surface contains 27 lines, but a singular cubic surface with [rational double points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_Val_singularity) contains fewer lines.

**Question:** Why is the number of lines equal to $\binom{8-r}{2}+n-1$, where $r$ is the total number of points in the Dynkin diagrams of the singularities, and $n$ the number of singularities? Is there a similar formula for other [del Pezzo surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_Pezzo_surface)?

**Example.** Consider the case $A_{1}A_{4}$. The total number of points is $5$ and there are $2$ singularities, so the number of lines equals $\binom{8-5}{2}+2-1=4$.

Comment: Have you checked the paper "On the Classification of Cubic Surfaces" (https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-19.2.245) by 
J. W. Bruce and  C. T. C. Wall? See page 255.

Comment: I've checked the paper. The point of my question is to prove the formula on p.255 without listing all types of singularities case-by-case.